# Что лучше использовать для рассылки писем?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, email, sendmail

Что лучше использовать для хранения почтовых адресов? БД или текстовый файл?

Comment: Как это вы решили использовать БД для рассылки писем? Как это должно выглядеть по-вашему?

Comment: Лучше использовать текстовый файл. Там больше настроек для отправки писем, больше режимов отправки писем.  Да и в текстовом файле не только отправка писем, но и много других сервисов есть. В общем универсальная вещь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я имел в виду Бд для хранения почтовых ящиков, чтобы потом по этим адресам разослать письма

Comment: Да вообще без разницы. Что удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всё же использовать базу данных, тот же MySQL, т.к. структурированные данные всегда будут лучше неразберихи в текстовом файле, да и гораздо эффективнее и удобнее в плане поиска и других операций с данными. Если не хотите реляционную базу данных - можете попробовать MongoDB.